# C# Singleton instance returns null

Tags: c#, oop, singleton

I'm developing a chess application in C#.

I've implemented ChessBoard as a singleton class which holds definitions for chess pieces. I'm able to access the ChessBoard instance from different classes. I even created a test class to see if I could access the ChessBoard instance, which proved successful.

However, in my ROOK class, when I try to access the ChessBoard instance, it returns null. Here's the code for ChessBoard class:

```
public sealed class ChessBoard 
{
   static readonly ChessBoard instance = new ChessBoard();

   static ChessBoard() 
   { }

   ChessBoard() 
   { }

   public static ChessBoard Instance
   {
      get
      {
         return instance;
      }
   }

   /* And some other methods and properties */
}
```

But when I call the instance of ChessBoard from the ROOK class it returns null. Here is the ROOK class:

```
public class ROOK : IPiece
{
   public int posx, posy;
   public int side;
   public List<Position> PossibleMoves = new List<Position>();

   public ROOK(int color, int x, int y)
   {
      posx = x;
      posy = y;
      side = color;
      UpdateMoveList();
   }

   public bool IsInLimits(int x, int y)
   { }

   public void UpdateMoveList()
   {
      ChessBoard boardinstance = ChessBoard.Instance;
      if (boardinstance == null) { MessageBox.Show("NULL"); }
      else
      { }
   }
}
```

The IPiece interface:

```
public interface IPiece
{
   IsInLimits(int x, int y);
   void UpdateMoveList();
}
```

As I said earlier, only in the ROOK class does the ChessBoard instance return null. In other classes it doesn't return null. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm not really sure why you'd design a chessboard as a singleton. Clearly you only want one, but there shouldn't be any need to force that this way. Additionally, it's fine for a rook to be a Rook. This comes across as you having a Knight, a Pawn and a ROOOOOOOOOOK!!!!!

Comment: Cross check perhaps it may be another `ChessBoard` class.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Its not possible because I only have one ChessBoard class

Comment: @Magus Im new to OOP in C# and seen in many places that its implemented as singleton.I know its not a must but I'm thinking of handling all the state checks and functions in the ChessBoard class.And doing a while loop in the main function running until its draw or checkmate

Comment: My point is that if you don't have a very specific use case, such as a file stream you need to keep open, you should not use a singleton. I and many others would say that even then you should try to find another way.

Comment: Regardless of using singletons being a good idea or not: that error should not be happening, at all. Maybe there is something else in your code that you are not showing us, or maybe you are referencing old binaries, I don't know. What I do know is that this code, as presented, cannot have the described behavior.

Comment: Yes as you said regardless of whether to use singleton or not I would expect this to work.When I call the instance of ChessBoard from the Form class in the Form_Load method or other classes there is no problem.Can it be because I initialize ROOK class inside ChessBoard class?Because when I initialize it in the Form class and call it there is no problem

Comment: @esonat - Yes, that is your issue.  The ChessBoard instance will not be instantiated at the point when you attempt to create the ROOK object inside of the constructor.  As a simple fix, you could create a static `SetupBoard` class that creates the pieces after the instance is created.

Comment: @SwDevMan81 can I write for example ROOK Wrook; inside ChessBoard and then instantiate it in another class as you said?

Comment: @esonat - Yeah that should be ok.  The issue comes when you make create the ROOK instance, the constructor is calling `UpdateMoveList` which is attempting to use the `ChessBoard` object.  If you dont instantiate the Rook class, that issue should go away.